Codeium chat not opening in android studio
I'm encountering an issue where Codeium Chat is not opening in Android Studio. I've tried various methods such as using the Codeium command palette and refactor options, but none of them seem to work.
Details:
Codeium Version: 1.8.28
Android Studio Version: Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1
Operating System: mac (macos sonoma 14.4 (23E214))
*Steps to Reproduce:
*
Open Android Studio.
Attempt to open Codeium Chat using the Codeium command palette or other methods.
Observe that Codeium Chat does not open as expected.
*Expected Behavior:
*
Clicking on the Codeium Chat option should open the chat interface within Android Studio.
*Actual Behavior:
*
Codeium Chat does not open, and there are no error messages or indications of what might be causing the issue.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Attempted to open Codeium Chat using different methods (command palette, refactor options).
Checked for any updates to Codeium and Android Studio.
Restarted Android Studio and the computer.
Verified that Codeium is properly installed and enabled in Android Studio settings.

Please report this to Codeium support at hello@codeium.com

no response from there side

Now codium provides a solution for how to run the plugin in Android Studio.
Install plugin and it guide you.
I provide steps as well. It helped me.

Help -> Find Action -> Registry
Uncheck ide.browser.jcef.sanbox.enable

Help -> Find Action -> Choose Boot Runtime for the IDE
Select the environment what supports JCEF


Hope it will help.

the first two steps work for me. thanks a lot.
